# Facebook Parse Auth not prompting the user to give permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform

I read: https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#fbusers

I implemented

```
<script>
  // Initialize Parse
  Parse.initialize("--", "--");

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
      appId      : '{--}', // Facebook App ID
      status     : true, // check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
      xfbml      : true
    });
    Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("public_profile,user_likes,email", {
  success: function(user) {
    if (!user.existed()) {
      alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
      console.log("user already exists ***";
    } else {
      console.log("new user created");
      alert("User logged in through Facebook! ***");
    }
    console.log("facebook parse activated ***");
  },
  error: function(user, error) {
    alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
  }
});

    // Run code after the Facebook SDK is loaded.
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Nothing pops up, what am I doing wrong. I want to ask the user for permissions and force them to log in.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not logging in correctly. Does this work?

```
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn({
    "id": "user's Facebook id number as a string",
    "access_token": "an authorized Facebook access token for the user",
    "expiration_date": "token expiration date of the format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    }, {
    success: function(user) {
        if (!user.existed()) {
            alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            console.log("user already exists ***";
        } else {
            console.log("new user created");
            alert("User logged in through Facebook! ***");
        }
        console.log("facebook parse activated ***");
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
        alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
    }
});
```